# Radio buttons enable/change CSS on submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, radio-button

I’m trying to change the css class of a submit button, when changing between two radio buttons. I can’t find a good example, and hope someone can help me out…

Here’s my form;

```
<form class="orderform">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="out" value="140" checked> <label for="out">I want A</label>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="in" value="40"> <label for="in">I want B</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Save changes" class="submit-btn-disabled" disabled="disabled">
</form>
```

Disabled (default) the submit button should look like above (class="submit-btn-disabled"), enabled it should look like class="submit-btn">, with a “mouseover” event:

```
<input type="submit" value=" Save changes" class="submit-btn">
```

The css classes here;

```
input.submit-btn-disabled{
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;     
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;   
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0em;
    border-radius: 0em;
    border: none;
    background-color: #c4daaa;
    padding: 0.8em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 1em;
}     

input.submit-btn{
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;     
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;   
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0em;
    border-radius: 0em;
    border: none;
    background-color: #3A7B30;
    padding: 0.8em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 1em;
} 

input.submit-btn:hover{
    background-color: #82bc00;
}
```

Comment: What is the issue? What are you expecting?

Comment: have a look at jquery `.toggleClass()` : https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/ By binding it to an event - such as `mouseover` - I think you should be able to accomplish what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to attach a click event to the radio buttons, and then use toggleClass, along with hasClass to modify the look of the submit button and its disabled state. For example

```
$("#in").on("click", function (e) {
    var btnDisabled = $(":submit").hasClass('submit-btn-disabled');
    if(btnDisabled) {
     $(":submit").toggleClass('submit-btn-disabled').toggleClass('submit-btn');
     $(":submit").prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick - http://jsfiddle.net/jpatel/FXp8E/

You need toggleClass function and css change -

JS

```
 $("[name=choice]").click(function(){
            $('.submit-btn').toggleClass('active');
    });
```

CSS

```
input.submit-btn.active{
background-color: #82bc00;}
```

so instead of changing the class of the submit-btn and submit-btn-disabled you can add or remove active class and that give you the behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well I didn't use **toggleClass()** as others suggested, so this code can be made better but I guess I managed to resolve what you are trying to do.

Here is the code:

**HTML** (just added an **id** for the button):

```
<form class="orderform">
   <input type="radio" name="choice" id="out" value="140" checked /> <label for="out">I want A</label>
   <input type="radio" name="choice" id="in" value="40" /> <label for="in">I want B</label><br />
   <input type="submit" value="Save changes" id='submit' class="submit-btn-disabled" disabled="disabled" /><br />
</form>
```

the **CSS** is the same

and the **jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#out').click(function() {
        $('#submit').addClass('submit-btn-disabled');
        $('#submit').removeClass('submit-btn');
    });
    $('#in').click(function() {
        $('#submit').removeClass('submit-btn-disabled');
        $('#submit').addClass('submit-btn');
    });
});
```

or check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/vugt7/

Answer (score 0):

I think we found the right solution! (Several days of searching up and down, solved in about 2 hours in here, me being very happy! :) I mixed some of the answers, when I added  `«<action=””  method="post">` to the form. The solution seems to work fine for me; (I hope this code is “compatible” with what’s called responsive websites and cross-browser compatibly and so on?)

```
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#out').click(function() {
        $('#submit').addClass('submit-btn-disabled');
        $('#submit').removeClass('submit-btn');
        $("#submit").prop('disabled', true);
    });
    $('#in').click(function() {
        $('#submit').removeClass('submit-btn-disabled');
        $('#submit').addClass('submit-btn');
        $("#submit").prop('disabled', false);
    });
});
});//]]>  
</script>
```

Seems to work like a rocket to me! :)